# Adding a fan box on a facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-page

I am trying to add a fan box on my fan page using the `<fb:fan>` tag. But it just doesn't get rendered on the page. 
I also tried using an `<fb:iframe>` as mentioned [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:fan), and setting its source to another file which contains the code for `<fb:fan>` tag. But even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This wont work in StaticFBML. The only work around is to use an iframe with StaticFBML. In the Iframe, you can then load the widget.